# Unit testing Project Reactor's publish

Tags: java, mockito, project-reactor

Suppose you need to mock a method that accepts a flux.

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class FooTest {
    @Mock Bar bar;
    @InjectMocks Foo foo;

    @Test
    void test() {
        when(bar.delete(any())).thenReturn(Mono.empty());

        StepVerifier.create(foo.deleteRelated("123"))
                .expectNext()
                .verifyComplete();
    }
}
```

```java
public class Foo {
    private final Bar bar;
    public Foo(Bar bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    public Mono<Void> deleteRelated(String id) {
        return Mono.just(id)
                .flatMapMany(this::findById)
                .log()
                .publish(bar::delete)
                .collectList()
                .then();
    }

    private Flux<String> findById(String id) {
        return Flux.just("a", "b", "c");
    }
}
```

```java
public class Bar {
    public Mono<Void> delete(Flux<String> vals) {
        return vals.buffer(3)
                .flatMap(this::deleteAFewAtATime)
                .collectList()
                .then();
    }

    private Mono<Void> deleteAFewAtATime(List<String> key) {
        return Mono.empty();
    }
}
```

Running this test results in an output with a cancel:

```
reactor.Flux.MonoFlatMapMany.1 : onSubscribe([Synchronous Fuseable] FluxArray.ArraySubscription)
reactor.Flux.MonoFlatMapMany.1 : cancel()
```

I wouldn't have expected the cancel signal to be emitted. I believe this is because the input to `bar.delete()` was not subscribed to.

How can I mock a function with a Flux as an input, and have that Flux be subscribed to?

Answer (score 0):

Your mock is okay, there's nothing wrong with that.

You should use transform() instead of publish() in your Foo class.
Since publish() turns your stream into the hot-publisher. This is the reason why you're seeing such effect.

So your code should look something like:

```
 public Mono<Void> deleteRelated(String id) {
        return findById(id)
                .log()
                .transform(bar::delete)
                .collectList()
                .then();
 }
```

Also there's no need to use `Mono.just(id)` with `flatMapMany()` since you can call your method with returning Flux directly